Facebook Pixel popup not working on https but working when i am removing ssl its working fine
I have developed the website (littlestepwelfarefoundation.com) on Django, taken the domain from Godaddy, hosted it on an EC2 Windows server, and took SSL certificate from ACM only.
When I am securing my site and routing http to https, facebook pixel is not firing, but when I am removing SSL and trying to access without HTTPS, it gets fired.
